# Adding alt text/title attributes to assets in a rich text field

Tags: assets, redactor, richtext

I have custom fields for `altText` and `title` on some asset image locations.

Wondering if there is a good way to have those automatically added when a user puts in an image from a rich text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing native that I can think of other than ditch the rich text field and use Matrix with a proper Assets field.

Comment: Thanks Brad, didn't think so, but wanted to check. Do you know offhand if this is possible from the Redactor side of things? Wondering if I can look at how you handle an image's src and follow suit.

Comment: I'm not sure if you could do it purely from the JS/Redactor side... I think you'd probably end up having a plugin that adds it's own RTE field type that extends the Craft one as well.

Comment: I'll give it a shot!